# What installs %AppData% Microsoft.NETCore.App

Tags: .net-framework

I'm curious to find what creates the folders under:

```
%AppData%Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
```

I've uninstalled all .NET Core SDKs but these still remain.  I've uninstalled VS2015 and VS2017 too.

Can I safely delete these folders?

Comment: *Can I safely delete these folders?* Yes, If you have uninstall .NET Core then the directory isn't used by anything.  As to what creates that folder, you installed .NET Core, thats what created it.

Comment: You should use the [.NET cleanup tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2017/05/26/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-cleanup-tool-and-detection-sample-code-now-support-net-framework-4-7/) if you want to make sure .NET Framework really was removed from your system

Answer (score 0):

OK, having had to rebuild my `Windows 10` machine from scratch, I have been watching this folder at all times during setup of applications.

It turns out this folder gets created during building of the asp.net core sources on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home) which downloads some stuff.

NOTE: `VS2017` doesn't install this and the .NET Clean up tool doesn't pick these folders up.